# Monitor Mode Debugging with an ARM M0 and GDB

Tags: arm, gdb, embedded

There doesn't seem to be too much comprehensive information on this topic. It seems to be something that is done quite often and easily in professional tools like Keil and IAR, but it can be a bit tricky/inflexible to write tooling around them that isn't in some special script/language they support.

How do you watch/stream live variable data from a GDB Server without stopping the processor? This can of course be done in some manner with Trace/SWO on non M0 processors, but the professional toolsets work well without this functionality.

Comment: Most IC debuggers utilize "cycle stealing" features of the MCU and debug over SWD/JTAG etc. You need some manner of hardware support in the specific MCU.

Comment: Hardware support? I'd be using the same programmer with GDB or the professional tool. I understand that there is some extra code loaded alongside, but that part seems to be kept intentionally opaque...

Comment: Hardware support as in every MCU has a specific debugging hardware peripheral intended to be used for this.

Comment: But can the OCD examine things without stopping and starting the cpu?  (which is pretty typical that you have to stop and start).  Other solutions are a rom monitor that is added to your binary by using a canned IDE/SDK and that gets timer based time slices setup by the canned library linked in for you by the IDE/SDK.  I would think in general if you want to do this on your own that is what you need to do.

Comment: GDB would/could connect to that rom monitor via a uart for example and the ocd isnt used at all, or you modify gdb to use some other path.

Comment: First you have to ask yourself why do I think I need this, decades of work at this level and I have never needed such a thing.  I have no use for GDB whatsoever.

Comment: Lundin, yes, of course, which is why I specifically mentioned the ARM M0 as the target. I don't believe there is a ton variance in this area across manufacturers.

Comment: old_timer, you've mention ROM monitoring several times, but that data isn't going to change by it's very nature unless you mean RAM... I have almost 2 decades of experience myself and have used live monitoring or simulations in some form or another for all sorts of things. I'm just trying to automate/instrument some things with tools that are easily accessible. I also need to get at some data points that change quite fast. My application and reason for doing this isn't relavent to the question being asked, but it's very useful for things in motor control algorithms.

Comment: old_timer wrote ROM **monitor**, not ROM **monitoring**.